# Python None comparison with is keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, nonetype, pep8

So the `is` keyword returns true only if the two arguments point to the same object. My question is related to the snippet below.

This snippet

```
number = None
if number is None:
    print("PEP 8 Style Guide prefers this pattern")
```

Outputs

```
>>PEP 8 Style Guide prefers this pattern
```

Does this mean when I assign `number = None` then it is only by reference, because `is` checks if it is the same object. I'm so confused why this happens?? Am I wrong?? Why was this design choice made?

Comment: All assignments in Python are by reference.

Comment: `None` is a language guaranteed singleton, if that's what you are asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of two reasons.

### 1. Assignments in Python are by reference.

In the following code

```py
x = object()
y = x
print(x is y)  # True
print(id(x))  # 139957673835552
print(id(y))  # 139957673835552
```

Calling `object()` creates a new structure in memory, whose unique identifier can be accessed with the `id()` function.
You can imagine `x` and `y` being arrows pointing to the same object, and this is why their underlying identifier is the same in both cases.

As such, when assigning `None` to a variable, you're just saying "`number` is an alias, an arrow pointing to *the object returned by* writing `None`". You can check that

```py
number = None
print(id(None), id(number))
```

will give you the same identifier two times. But wait! What if you do it for a big number like `100000`?

```py
number = 100000
print(id(100000), id(number))  # Different values!
```

This means that the same literal, written two times, can return different objects, bringing up the next reason.

### 2. The language guarantee for None

Note that no matter how many times you get the `None` identifier, you get the same one.

```py
print(id(None))  # 139957682420224
print(id(None))  # 139957682420224
print(id(None))  # 139957682420224
```

This is because writing `None` doesn't create a new object, as in the first example, because the language specification [guarantees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) that there's only one possible object of `NoneType` in memory. In other words, **there's only one possible object returned by writing `None`**, making comparisons with `is` work as expected. This is a good design choice: There's only *one* canonical way for saying that a variable (*an arrow*) points to *nothingness*.

In fact, using `is` is encouraged as the Pythonic way of checking that a variable is `None`.

You can also get the *class* of the object by writing

```py
NoneType = type(None)
```

and notice how

```py
NoneType() is None
```

is true.

*Note: The uniqueness property is also satisfied by other literals, particularly small numbers, for performance reasons.*

Comment: Regarding the note: that's an implementation detail, not a language guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

All assignments are by reference (see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)). However, the language guarantees that `None` is the only object of its type. That value is created at startup, and the literal `None` will *always* produce a reference to that value.

```
>>> a = None;  b = None
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> a is b
True
```

Compare to a literal like `12345`, which may or may not produce a reference to an existing value of type `int`.

```
>>> a = 12345; b = 12345
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = 12345
>>> b = 12345
>>> a is b
False
```

*Why* this produces different results isn't really important, other than to say that an implementation *can* create new objects from `int` literals if it prefers.